# Open application with single instance

Tags: android

When I minimize my app and do any other operation on the mobile device and click back on my app icon (to relaunch), the app is switch back to where it was previously. But it opens with new instance of it. That means if I press Back button the new launch app is closed but previously opened app is not closed.

So what I want is if my app is already running and then minimized and click on the launch icon, I just want to **only one app instance** to.

Comment: Did you call the INTENT- NEW_TASK in any of your activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get familiar with Activity [launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes).

In your case you could set in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in case your Activity is the one that was visible last when app went to the background

or set:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: Does not work for me. This has to be added in application tag right?

Answer (score 1):

You can override onBackPressed in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


        super.onBackPressed();

     this.moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to recall that application from system tray, instead of relaunching, whenever you press your application icon it creates a new instance from your system tray. So it is common practice to recall application from system tray instead of relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

if you reqire just single instance of your activity set activity as below in your manifeast file...

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

Comment: It's good for having single Activity instance, not single application instance. singleInstance mode allows only one Activity per task. It's not recommended mode for most cases.